# Uploaded file attaching with the Guid Name , not just the file name

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-core-mvc

I want to upload a file when Leave is applied and it should show in the Leave details page for that specific leave .

When I upload the file on the Apply leave page it gets uploaded with the right name(document.docx), but not on the Leave Details page  (a2030420-15fe-47b3-9dac-748ecc30dfa8_document.docx).

**I want the document to seen as (document.docx) on the LeaveDetails page as well. The jquery is not getting applied on the LeaveDetails page.**

Thanks for the help
Here are the Models:

```
 public  class ApplyLeave : Entity 
    {
      public string FilePath { get; set; }
      public ICollection<EmployeeLeave> EmployeeLeaves { get; set; }
    }

   public class ApplicationUser 
   {
     public string FilePath { get; set; }
     public ICollection<EmployeeLeave> EmployeeLeaves { get; set; }

   }
 public class EmployeeLeave : Entity
    {
        public int LeaveId {get;set;}
        public ApplyLeave Leave { get; set; }

        public int  EmployeeId {get;set;}
        public ApplicationUser Employee { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Status")]
        public string LeaveStatus { get; set; }//: pending

    }
 public class ApplyLeaveViewModel
    {  public IFormFile File { get; set; }
    }
```

These are the views and the jquery

```
Apply.cshtml

    <div class="container-fluid mt-5">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h3>Apply Leave</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" asp-action="Apply">
      <div class="form-group col-6">
                            <label asp-for="File" class="col-auto col-form-label small form-text">Attach Documents</label>
                            <div class="col custom-file">
                                <input asp-for="File" class="form-control custom-file-input" />
                                <label class="custom-file-label">Choose File...</label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
</form>

@section Scripts {

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.custom-file-input').on("change", function () {
                var fileName = $(this).val().split("\\").pop();
                $(this).next('.custom-file-label').html(fileName);
            });

        });
    </script>
}

MyleaveDetails.cshtml
@model EmployeeManagement2.Core.Entities.EmployeeLeave

<div class="container-fluid mt-5">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
            <h3>Leave Details</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
            <form method="post" asp-action="MyLeaveDetails">


                <input type="hidden" asp-for="LeaveId" />
                <input type="hidden" asp-for="EmployeeId" />

   <div class="form-group col-4">
                        <label asp-for="@Model.Employee.FilePath" class="col-auto col-form-label small form-text">Attach Documents</label>
                        <div class="col custom-file">
                            <input  readonly class="form-control  custom-file-input"  asp-for="@Model.Employee.FilePath" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
</form>
@section Scripts {

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.custom-file-input').on("change", function () {
                var fileName = $(this).val().split("\\").pop();
                $(this).next('.custom-file-label').html(fileName);
            });

        });
    </script>
}
```

These are the controller actions for the applyLeave and the Leave details

```
  [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Apply(ApplyLeaveViewModel applyLeaveViewModel)
        {

            string uniqueFileName = null;

            string uploadsFolder = Path.Combine(_webHostEnvironment.WebRootPath, "Files");
            uniqueFileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + "_" + applyLeaveViewModel.File.FileName;

            string filePath = Path.Combine(uploadsFolder, uniqueFileName);
            FileStream fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create);
            applyLeaveViewModel.File.CopyTo(fs);


            var mapped = _mapper.Map<ApplyLeave>(applyLeaveViewModel);

            var newLeave = await _leaveRepository.AddNewLeave(mapped);
            var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);
            user.FilePath = uniqueFileName;

            var userid = user.Id;
            var leaveId =  newLeave.ID;

            EmployeeLeave employeeLeave = new EmployeeLeave();
            employeeLeave.LeaveId = leaveId;
            employeeLeave.EmployeeId = userid;
            employeeLeave.LeaveStatus = "Pending";
            
            

            //add the instance to the 
           await _employeeLeaveRepository.AddEmployeeNewLeave(employeeLeave);


            return RedirectToAction("GetAllMyLeaves");
        }

  public async Task<IActionResult> MyLeaveDetails(int leaveId)
        {
           var leave = await _employeeLeaveRepository.GetLeaveById(leaveId);
           
            return View(leave);
        }
```

Comment: Where are you seeing the document with guid name on LeaveDetails? The view has a POST method but the controller only has a GET. Do you mean when the view is loaded it has the wrong name?

Comment: Yes , when the view (LeaveDetails ) is loaded  it  wrong name is displayed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what's happening, in short, is that you are adding the GUID to the uploaded file name, saving it to DB and then outputting the GUID-containing file name into the view.

The following misses out chunks of your code but hopefully explains what's happening:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Apply(ApplyLeaveViewModel applyLeaveViewModel)
{
  // adds guid to create unique name
  // e.g. a2030420-15fe-47b3-9dac-748ecc30dfa8_document.docx
  uniqueFileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + "_" + applyLeaveViewModel.File.FileName;

  // load User entity and set it's FilePath property to string with Guid
  var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);

  // this is the key line
  user.FilePath = uniqueFileName;

  // if user is from same db context then the updated FilePath property
  // will be detected and saved when dbContext.SaveChanges() called
  await _employeeLeaveRepository.AddEmployeeNewLeave(employeeLeave);

  // in db ApplicationUser.FilePath = a2030420-15fe-47b3-9dac-748ecc30dfa8_document.docx
}

public async Task<IActionResult> MyLeaveDetails(int leaveId)
{
  // EmployeeLeave.Employee was updated above
  var leave = await _employeeLeaveRepository.GetLeaveById(leaveId);
}
```

Then in the view you use the .FilePath property, which will contain the guid. `<input readonly class="form-control custom-file-input" asp-for="@Model.Employee.FilePath" />`

The solution will depend on your individual requirements but you could store both the fileName that was submitted (`document.docx`) and the filePath (`somewhere://a2030420-15fe-47b3-9dac-748ecc30dfa8_document.docx`)

*Edit*

If you are not attempting to upload the file then you don't need the `$('.custom-file-input').on("change", function ()` handler. You will need to change the value of `@Model.Employee.FilePath` before rendering the view - either by using a [ViewModel](https://dotnettutorials.net/lesson/view-model-asp-net-core-mvc/) or manually rendering the `<input />` element and using string manipulation on `@Model.Employee.FilePath` to display just the document name.

Comment: I am using jQuery to split the fileName and just have the document.docx portion visible . It Works fine in the Apply View but not in the MyLeaveDetails View . So shouldn't that jQuery split the fileName?

Comment: The jQuery in both views is trying to split different values. One has the GUID and one doesn't. I'd expect the suggestion by by @chetham-m to work. If it doesn't you'll need to provide more information

Comment: I tried it but it does not work.  What more information do you require?

Comment: Added more details on answer.

Comment: I was able to solve the issue and yes did not need the jQuery  and had to manually manipulate the FilePath. Your explanation helped me in the right direction .Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

Add `fileName =fileName.split("_").pop();` line in the details page.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.custom-file-input').on("change", function () {
                var fileName = $(this).val().split("\\").pop();
                fileName =fileName.split("_").pop()
                $(this).next('.custom-file-label').html(fileName);
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the problem by adding the following in the LeaveController action method(MyLeaveDetails). I Split the uploaded Guid file using substring to get the original name of the file. Also I did not need the jquery script for this method

```
 var file = leave.Employee.FilePath;
 string docPath = file.Substring(file.IndexOf("_") + 1);
 leave.Employee.FilePath = docPath;
```

So the method is like this now

```
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<IActionResult> LeaveDetails(int  leaveId)
        {
            var leave = await _employeeLeaveRepository.GetLeaveById(leaveId);

            var file = leave.Employee.FilePath;
            string docPath = file.Substring(file.IndexOf("_") + 1);
            leave.Employee.FilePath = docPath;

            return View(leave);
        }
```